# jquery .animate makes object jump

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a really simple animation. I want div.box at (right:10px) to move to left:10px when it is clicked. The container width could be variable, so it's crucial that the left edge of the div always animates to left:10px. With the code below this does not work. I've successfully hacked a way for it to move by obtaining the width of `<body>` when the div is clicked and doing some calculations, but it and breaks down after the browser is resized. Is there a better way to accomplish this? I suspect the problem with the JS below stems from the fact that the position of div.box, `right: 10px;`, is not being removed after the JS runs.

***JSFIDDLE:*** http://jsfiddle.net/5GL5r/15/

***CSS***

```
.box {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

***JS***

```
$(".box").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({left:"10px"});
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with augmenting `right` instead? Like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chevL/).

Comment: You can't set a right property, and then animate a left property as jQuery has no idea where to start the animation, as there is no left property to begin with. Set an initial left property and it works.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/5GL5r/18/

Comment: is that what u want ? http://jsfiddle.net/5GL5r/19/

Comment: Sorry, there is some confusion. I don't want `div.box` to move left 10px, I want it to move to left:10px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animating on the `right` property (as you already tried) and afterwards setting the `left` property might work for you. I will only 'break' if you resize your window during animation, although after the animatin is finished everything will look ok again.

```
$(".box").click(function() {
    var parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();
    var newRight = parentWidth - $(this).width() - 10;
    $(this).animate({right: newRight}, function() {
        // On animation finish:
        $(this).css('right', 'auto')
               .css('left', '10px');
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5GL5r/16/)

(Edit, after first comment):

JQuery.animate calculates the step-size at the beginning. So if you work with pixels that won't work well if your parent-div resizes during the animation. If you however work with percentages it will work. Following might be an quite ugly hack:

New CSS (give wrap a padding of the width of your box, and box an left margin of 100%)

```
.wrap {
    height: 50px;
    background: #aaa;
    position:relative; 
    top:0;
    left:0;
    padding: 10px 110px 10px 10px;
}

.box {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background: red;
    margin-left: 100%;
}
```

And animate the left-margin to 0% using javascript:

```
$(".box").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        marginLeft: '0%'
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5GL5r/21/) (I've given it a very slow speed, so you can try resizing the frame)

Comment: That's definitely the position I'd want the div to move to. But if someone rotates their phone or changes browser size it will break. Is there a less hacky way to accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks. This solution works nicely and uses minimal javascript.